# Best way to reload ASP.NET Core Razor 2.2 web page when specific database field changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I want to refresh an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor page when specific data changes in the SQL Server database table.  I only want to refresh the full page when the background data changes (not using a consistent meta refresh) since this page will be displayed 24/7 on a business area TV screen.  The constant meta refresh will become annoying to the users who are forced to watch the screen.

I'm new to Razor so will an expert Razor programmer please suggest the best method.  I found an AJAX method in searching, but I'm hoping there is a better way built into either Razor or C#.  Also, I have read a few blogs suggesting web sockets which I know nothing about.  Whatever method chosen, I can build a yes/no flag into the database so the site will refresh when the flag column is set to yes meaning the page needs to reload.

Comment: Use SignalR. SignalR will be best fit for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TanvirArjel - I took your advice implementing SignalR and it works great.

In case someone is looking for SignalR details, I started with a [SignalR Chat template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) on the Microsoft site then modified the hub javascript to perform a refresh on all user screens rather than sending one piece of data at a time.  SignalR has much better features to push data, but I was looking for a quick turn around hence the page refresh.

Two things to keep in mind.  I spent time looking into the .NET Framework version of SignalR which was a waste since I’m using ASP.NET Core 2.2.  Also, I use a lot of datetime calls in my site to ensure users can only modify recent posts (eg: only show if post occurred in last 60 seconds).  The date based if statements threw off the SignalR functionality so I ended up calling SignalR with other authentication conditions.  I haven’t taken the time to figure out the date issues since I had a work around.